# Meteor kitchen adding subpages in User Accounts example

Tags: meteor, meteor-kitchen

I am trying to learn meteor, so I created few sample which worked fine. I searched for boiler plate and came across http://www.meteorkitchen.com/examples which is very helpful.

I setup the http://generator-accounts.meteor.com/ and added Login with facebook and google out of which Google worked fine.

The sample I am working on need sub pages for which I referred Subpages example and modified code but it is not working as expected.

[image: This is how the app looks like]
Now the requirement is whenever I click on menu the content should be displayed below the menu.

So I modified the template

```
<template name="HomePrivate">
    <div class="page-container container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-inverse" role="navigation">
                <div class="navbar-container container">
                    <div id="listing" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
                        <ul id="menu-items" class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li id="menu-item-simple" class="{{menuItemClass 'home_public'}}">
                                <a href="{{pathFor 'home_private.general_information'}}">
                                    <span class="item-title">
                                        General Information
                                    </span>
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div id="subcontent">
                {{> yield region='HomePrivateSubcontent'}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

and in route

```
this.route("home_private.general_information", {path: "/home_private/general_information", controller: "GeneralInformationController"});
```

Now when I click on menu item it replaces the menu as well whereas my understanding is the content should be rendered in

```
{{> yield region='HomePrivateSubcontent'}}
```

Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved the problem.

Please use the YAML version instead of JSON version to setup locally.
https://github.com/perak/kitchen-examples/tree/master/example-subpages

and some changes in controller were required.

Comment: Hi Nitin, 
What is the best way to start/learn meteor?
Do you think meteor-kitchen is a good source to start development?